# Bind Listview columns to TextBox

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I have a table `CompanyMainFile` that contains many columns in SQL Server. I also have a VB Windows forms application.

In the app, I have a `ListView` showing only 2 columns from this table (`License No` and `Company Name`).

How do I click on the `License No` column in the `ListView` and get all the data into `TextBox` controls?

See screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Run a `SELECT` query, where `License No` = the value in the selected cell

Comment: Is it your intention to only retrieve those two columns initially and then get the rest on a per-record basis or are you getting all the data upfront?

Comment: i want only retrieve those two columns initially and then get the rest on a per-record basis. when i click on License No i want to get the data for this specific License No.